PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - cudnn=8.6.0.163*
I am getting this error while installing this package in my conda env
I have tried different commands which can be used to install the package  but never succeeded.
conda install -c conda-forge cudnn=8.6.0.163
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
 - anaconda
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - cudnn=8.6.0.163*

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - defaults
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.



Do you absolutely need that specific version?

There is no such version available from conda-forge for windows, you can check with conda search:
conda search cudnn

# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
cudnn                       7.6.5.32      h2cb8ba8_1  conda-forge
cudnn                       7.6.5.32      h36d860d_1  conda-forge
cudnn                       7.6.5.32      h37a4af2_1  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.0.5.39      h36d860d_1  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.0.5.39      h37a4af2_1  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.0.5.39      hfe7f257_1  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.1.0.77      h37a4af2_0  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.1.0.77      h3e0f4f4_0  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.2.0.53      h754d62a_0  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.2.0.53      hae0fe6e_0  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.2.1.32      h754d62a_0  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.2.1.32      hae0fe6e_0  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.3.2.44      hf5f08ae_0  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.3.2.44      hf5f08ae_1  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.4.0.27      hf5f08ae_0  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.4.0.27      hf5f08ae_1  conda-forge
cudnn                       8.4.1.50      hf5f08ae_0  conda-forge

You will need to select one of the available versions
